# CodeIgniter] Empty Optgroup using form_dropdown

Tags: forms, codeigniter

```
    foreach($product_categories as $product_category)
    {
        $options = array();
        foreach($series_categories as $series_category)
        {
            if($product_category['prod_cate_idx'] == $series_category['prod_cate_idx'])
            {
                $options[$series_category['series_cate_idx']] = $series_category['series_cate_name'];
            }
        }
        if(count($options) > 0)
        {
            $series_category_dropdown[$product_category['prod_cate_name']] = $options;
        }
        else
        {
            //problem here. how to make a empty optgroup?
            $series_category_dropdown[$product_category['prod_cate_name']] = array('', NULL);
        }
        empty($options);
    }
```

Okay, i have two categories here - one is product categories and the other is series categories that goes under one of product categories. A product category may or may not have series categories.

I need to make a dropdown menu like this:

- A

  - a
  - a
  - a
  - a
- B

  - b
  - b
  - b
- C
- D
- E

  - e
  - e
  - e

The code given is perfectly working except that I don't know how to deal with the empty optgroups :S

I googled tons to figure out how to generate empty optgroups like C & D but haven't found  solutions or anyone has tried it yet :(   Does anyone have a clue how I should generate a multi-dimensional array to make it happen?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through CI's core code, that is not possible. However, there is a really easy fix for it by editing a core file, the reason I think you could "get away" with editing a core file here is because it is not going to affect anything else with your dropdown menu:

1. Navigate to `/system/helpers/form_helper.php`
2. Find the `form_dropdown` function
3. Add `if(empty($optgroup_val)) continue;` after the `optgroup` loop

You `foreach` loop should now look like this:

```
foreach ($val as $optgroup_key => $optgroup_val)
{
    // add this line
    if(empty($optgroup_val)) continue;

    $sel = (in_array($optgroup_key, $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

    $form .= '<option value="'.$optgroup_key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $optgroup_val."</option>\n";
}
```

As I said above, usually I wouldn't recommend editing a core file, but instead extending the CI helper class, and so does CI (it's just a bit more work):

> To "extend" Helpers, create a file in your application/helpers/ folder
>   with an identical name to the existing Helper, but prefixed with MY_
>   (this item is configurable. See below.).

Reference: [**"Extending" Helpers** in Helper Functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)